# How to imply a grid system in VUE js dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a code

```
    <div id="TechnicalQuestions">
            <h1 class="h1">Technical Questions</h1>
        <template v-for="i in 4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columns">
                <template>
                <div class="column" v-if="i%2==0">
                    <p>{{ aList[i] }} {{ i }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column" v-else>
                    <p>{{ aList[i] }} {{ i}} </p>
                </div>
                </template>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
<script>
 //I have a list
aList=["Question1","Question2","Question3","Question4","Question5","Question6"]
</script>
```

what I want is something like

Question1 Question2
Question3 Question4
Question5 Question6

Comment: why are you doing v-for="i in 4" in your code and why haven't you defined aList in data?

Comment: I have defined aList in data ata() {
            return {
                techQuesList: [],
                dataQuesList: [],
                aList: [" ","Question1","Question2", "Question3","Question4","Question5", "Question6"]

            }

Comment: i want to print like a grid in 2*3 = 6

Comment: Use css flexbox  and iterate it using v-for loop.